# Data is not display after insertion through Bootstrap modal with jquery ajax in php Mysqli

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-modal

Data is not display after insert through bootstrap modal with ajax in php mysqli.

[image]

[image]

jQuery Ajax code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    fetch_data();   

    function fetch_data() {
            var action = "fetch";
            $.ajax({
                url: 'action.php',
                method: 'post',
                data: {action: action},
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#all_table_data").html(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });

    function addData() {
         var formData = new FormData($('#employee_insert_form')[0]);

         formData.append('action', 'add');
         $.ajax({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'action.php',
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            success: function (response) {
                $("#all_table_data").html(response);
                $('#empInsert').modal('hide');
                fetch_data();
             }
          });
      }
```

Comment: Did you inspect the XHR in the browser's dev tools? Does it return what you think it does? Is anything inserted at all?

Comment: Also, are you seeing any errors in your PHP error log?

Comment: @MatthewTurland no any errors , data is inserted but not display after modal hide.

Comment: @KUMAR Is your `action.php` script returning any data? If you run `console.log(response)` in your `success` function, what does it show?

Comment: @MatthewTurland please see this my code of action.php .

Comment: @KUMAR You should be using [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) for your database query, or else filenames with apostrophes could cause issues, among other things.

What I'm seeing of your PHP code is in fact not sending any output back to the JS code requesting it, as I suspected. If you want your JS code to receive data, you need to have PHP output that data (e.g. via `echo`).

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP code never return anything to your view. So try to echo result of select * from tbl_employee after the insertion